# Why is there a type error in this f# expression?

Tags: f#

first day working in F#. I've spent some time in Haskell and am trying to learn F# to work with some existing .net code. Why is this code angry with me? What's the equivalent to :t? How would I add a type annotation to main?

```
type Color = Red | Green
[<EntryPoint>]
let main = 
    let a = Red
    if a = Red then
       printfn "hi!"
     else
       printfn "no!"
```

Comment: You do not necessarily to use the `main` in such a simple application: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DAuzG8

Comment: @FoggyFinder - good point, it is often best to start messing around in FSI, using scripts in VS / VSCode / Ionide / etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The signature of the function with an `[<EntryPoint>]` attribute (e.g. `main`) should be `string[] -> int` in your version it is missing the `string[]` parameter and a return value of type `int`

You can remedy it by adding those in:

```
type Color = Red | Green
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = //argv added here is inferred to be string[]
    let a = Red
    if a = Red then
       printfn "hi!"
     else
       printfn "no!"
    0 //Return 0, all OK
```

Without the `0` at the end to return an `int`, you are returning `unit` (the result of `printfn`).

Comment: Ah. I'm trying to run that in interactive, and I have to use eg [|"1"; "2"; "3"|]. What do the pipes do here?

Comment: Does that make a strict list?

Comment: Try it in FSI :). With `let a = [| "a"; |]` = `val a : string [] = [|"a"|]` Without: `val a : string [] = [|"a"|]` = `val l : string list = ["l"]`.

Comment: One makes an [Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/arrays-%5Bfsharp%5D) the other makes a [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/lists-%5Bfsharp%5D).

Comment: Oh, and also check out https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/

Comment: One more question, if you wouldn't mind - do I need to do something to make this work? let sum = printfn . List.sum $ [1..100] Like do I need to tell it to import List?

Comment: Ah, is that how you do composition in f#?

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion - feel free to ask new Questions on SO, the comments are not really designed for new questions - and F# questions have a very fast answer time.

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion: The direct translations of Haskell `.` and `$` in F# are `<<` and `<|`, respectively. However, the most common style in F# is to start with the initial argument and use the `|>` operator to pipe it through functions until you get the final result. Likewise, function composition is typically written left to right with the `>>` operator.